# Microsoft SQL SERVER : GROUP rows by 30 minutes according to first different row (rows can have different days and time)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, group-by

I have a transaction table with different columns for the sake of the example I only keep the related ones to question.

My table: transaction

```
id  TransactionTime             idClient 
---------------------------------------------
1   2019-05-29 09:37:30.000     1531201523215
1   2019-05-29 09:37:30.000     1531201523215
2   2019-05-29 10:20:06.000     1531201523215
3   2019-05-29 10:45:19.000     1531201523215
4   2019-05-29 10:50:19.000     1531201523215
5   2019-05-29 10:51:43.000     1531201523215
6   2019-05-29 10:57:36.000     1531201523215
6   2019-05-29 10:57:36.000     1531201523215
7   2019-05-30 10:07:14.000     1531201523215
8   2019-05-30 10:37:12.000     1531201523215
9   2019-05-30 10:38:11.000     1531201523215
10  2019-05-30 10:46:17.000     1531201523215
```

What I want to achieve is Group rows within 30 minutes of each other, the desired output would be

```
id  TransactionTime             idClient            Count
----------------------------------------------------------
1   2019-05-29 09:37:30.000     1531201523215       2  
2   2019-05-29 10:20:06.000     1531201523215       2
4   2019-05-29 10:50:19.000     1531201523215       4
7   2019-05-30 10:07:14.000     1531201523215       2      
9   2019-05-30 10:38:11.000     1531201523215       2
```

I tried using :

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        PARTITION BY tl.idClient
        ,(dateadd(minute, (datediff(second, 0, tl.TransactionTime) / 60 / 30) * 30, 0)) ORDER BY tl.idClient
            ,tl.TransactionTime
        ) AS filter_row
```

But I couldn't achieve what I wanted ... Been stuck for 4  days now... Please Help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a recursive query for this. The idea is to start from the first record per `id_client` (according to `transaction_time`), and then walk the group by ascending `transaction_time`.

```
with 
    tab as (
        select t.*, row_number() over(partition by id_client order by transaction_time) rn
        from mytable t
    ),
    cte as (
        select id, id_client, rn, transaction_time from tab where rn = 1
        union all
        select 
            t.id,
            t.id_client,
            t.rn,
            case when t.transaction_time > dateadd(minute, 30, c.transaction_time)
                then t.transaction_time
                else c.transaction_time
            end
        from cte c
        inner join tab t on t.id_client = c.id_client and t.rn = c.rn + 1

    )
select min(id) id, transaction_time, id_client, count(*) cnt
from cte 
group by id_client, transaction_time
order by id_client, transaction_time
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=be154ca272cebf8d13621a9478e6990c)**:

```
id | transaction_time        | id_client     | cnt
-: | :---------------------- | :------------ | --:
 1 | 2019-05-29 09:37:30.000 | 1531201523215 |   2
 2 | 2019-05-29 10:20:06.000 | 1531201523215 |   2
 4 | 2019-05-29 10:50:19.000 | 1531201523215 |   4
 7 | 2019-05-30 10:07:14.000 | 1531201523215 |   2
 9 | 2019-05-30 10:38:11.000 | 1531201523215 |   2
```

Comment: It's me again, your solution works like a charm, but is there a way to make it faster with analytics i mean using rank() functions etc.. cause I have like more than 50 million rows.. And this looks like taking for ever

Comment: @YassineELbaza: yes recursion is slow on a large dataset. Here, we need recursion because you want maximum a 30 minutes gap between the *first* and last row in the group. If you were to start a new group everytime there is a  30 minutes gap between *two consecutive* records, no recursion is needed.